# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors and matrix P and matrix D

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

So I have matrix $M_{4\times4} := \begin{pmatrix}13 &0& 0& 0\\ 0 &11 &0 &0\\ 0& 0& 1& -1\\ 0& 0& 1& 1\end{pmatrix}$. I have to find an invertible matrix $P$ and diagonal matrix $D$ so that $M = PDP^{-1}$.

I have already calculated eigenvalues to be $11$ and $13$ and the corresponding eigenvectors are $\begin{pmatrix}0 &t &0 &0\end{pmatrix}^T$ and $\begin{pmatrix}t &0 &0 &0\end{pmatrix}^T$ respectively. However, from what I understand I need four eigenvectors and four eigenvalues to make $P$ and $D$. What am I missing?

Comment: You are missing two other eigenvalues (which are complex numbers)

Comment: do complex numbers count as eigen values?

Comment: oh yes thank you for suggesting! I do miss the complex eigenvalues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial is $(13-x)(11-x)((1-x)^2+1)$.  So $x=1\pm i$ are the other two eigenvalues.  Now you need to find the corresponding eigenvectors and form a matrix, $P$, consisting in eigenvectors.  We will get $D=\begin{pmatrix}13&0&0&0\\0&11&0&0\\0&0&1+i&0\\0&0&0&1-i\end{pmatrix}$.